# Binomial and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Please help me solve this problem.

Show that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k{n \choose 2k+1} = (n-2)2^{n-3}$$

Comment: Show that you have attempted to solve the problem on your own. When we know where you are stuck, we can help you better.

Comment: Do you want an algebraic or combinatorial solution ? ... and can you share your attempts ... so we have an idea of level ?

Comment: I need combinatorial solution.

Comment: There is a really neat combinatorial proof ... Hint: $\text{Odd}+1+\text{Odd}=\text{Odd}$.

Comment: Add the tag "combinatorial proof" & tell me if you need more than the hint above.

Comment: I added the tag, but I don't understand the hint Donald.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Your question is stated as an isolated problem without providing context or any effort of your own. Please edit your question to improve it. As of now it is likely to attract down votes and get closed. I recommend reading [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to improve the quality of this and future questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\frac{(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose 2k+1} x^{2k+1}$$
$$\frac{(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n}{2x}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose 2k+1} x^{2k}$$
Differentiate w.r.t. $x$ both sides
$$\frac{n(1+x)^{n-1}+n(1-x)^{n-1}}{2x}+\frac{(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n}{-2x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2k {n \choose 2k+1} x^{2k-1}$$
Now put $x=1$ in above, to get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k{n \choose 2k+1}=2^{n-3}(n-2)$$

the upper limit of the sum could be $[n/2]$ or $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $[n]= \{ 1,2, \cdots,n\}$ with their usual order.

Choose an element of $[n]$ excluding the first and last elements. Now choose an odd number of elements before and an odd number of elements after. It easy to see that this enumerates to $(n-2)2^{n-3}$.

Alternatively choose an odd ($ \geq 3$) number of elements from $[n]$ and now choose on of the "even" elements from this subset.